# Computer not booting unless power-cycled subsequent to windows shutdowns

Tags: boot, bios, multi-boot, operating-systems, grub2

..however, this issue doesn't happen if I shutdown from Linux Mint on this dual booting UEFI system.

So, if I shutdown (or restart or hibernate) from Windows 10, the POST stops before I get to the grub menu and I have to hit the power button twice to get to the menu, whereas if I shut down or restart from Linux Mint it goes back to the grub menu and continues to boot just fine.

I just bought this used pc, and installed an SSD, cloned the Win10 partition from the HDD, then installed Mint next to is on the SSD.  All should be GPT filesystem.

This is my first time with an UEFI system, and I'm a bit baffled with it.  I tried Ubuntu boot-repair, which didn't fix but output this which might be useful:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WsfHrsnqst/

edit: The pc is a Lenovo i5 6400 700-25ish

Comment: Try resetting UEFI and check for updates.

Comment: Which computer? Please click on [edit] and add the make and model; the model number should come from the serial number plate. A question should, by the time it's answered, contain everything needed to explain the issue.

Comment: I had already updated the BIOS/UEFI and tried resetting the default options in the BIOS/UEFI, but no luck @davidbaumann

Comment: Did you check for updates

Comment: Do you mean something other than updated BIOS firmware @davidbaumann?  I had updated this to the latest from the Lenovo support site.  Windows is upto date, as is Linux Mint.

Comment: I don't really understand - is there some system state that is written to the booting sequence after Windows is shutdown?  I don't quite get what it is that is being 'reset ' by power-cycling past it.

Comment: I've ended up reinstalling both partitions on a MBR table, and no longer have the issue.  So, I suppose the question still stands, but I won't be able to test any answers.